# meaning of 'put down'

Tags: vocabulary

I looked up 'ley' in my Concise Oxford Dictionary and found the following definition.

a piece of land temporarily put down to grass, clover, etc., in contrast to permanent pasture.

Can anyone tell me what 'put down' means? I cannot find its meaning in the dictionary.

Comment: I have never heard that way of using 'put down'. To me it can mean (as others have noted) 'to kill an animal that is useless' or 'to insult' or more literally 'to place and release an object below oneself'. In context, this is understandable as 'to let go unused as'. It is most likely known in a farming context.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it means set aside. Temporarily [fallow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallow); cultivated land that is allowed to lie idle during the growing season.

Comment: Looks right to me. Note that in the context of an animal, "put down" is a euphemism for killing it.

Comment: @T.E.D. And it can also be a term for an insult.

Comment: Can you find this sense of 'put down' in the dictionary?

Comment: @Apollyon Definition of the word "put" - To place in a specified location; set